# I am using cytoscape set "text-opacity:0" in style but it does not work

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js version 3.7.0 to show a relation graph.The desired effect is when click one node, the other nodes and edges turn to unusable state.I do not find one attribute to achieve the goal.I am trying to another way: add click event to node, when the node is clicked, set all element "opacity":"0.2", "text-opacity":"0", then set the current node "opacity":"1", "text-opacity":"1", the opacity attribute is work, but the text-opacity is not, only scroll the mouse to zoom-in the graph, the label text on nodes and edges are invisible, scroll the mouse to zoom-out the graph the label text visible again.In my submission, when "text-opacity":"0" been setted, whether zoom or not, the label text should be invisible.

cytoscape.js version is 3.7.0.
I tried to added click event to node, when the node is clicked, set all element "opacity":"0.2", "text-opacity":"0", then set the current node "opacity":"1", "text-opacity":"1", only scroll the mouse to zoom-in the graph the "text-opacity":"0", it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Cytoscape.js</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* cytoscape graph */
        #cy {
            height: 600px;
            width: 1200px;
            background-color: #00f9f9;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let highlightLineWidth = "3px";
        let normalLineWidth = "1px";
        $(function () {
            let edgeMouseOverHandler = function (evt) {
                evt.target.style('width', highlightLineWidth);
            };

            let edgeMouseOutHandler = function (evt) {
                evt.target.style('width', normalLineWidth);
            };

            let nodeMouseOverHandler = function (evt) {
                evt.target.connectedEdges().style('width', highlightLineWidth);
            };

            let nodeMouseOutHandler = function (evt) {
                evt.target.connectedEdges().style('width', normalLineWidth);
            };

            let cy = cytoscape({
                container: document.getElementById('cy'),
                style: [
                    {
                        selector: 'node[label = "Person"]',
                        css: {
                            'background-color': '#6FB1FC', 'content': 'data(name)', "font-size": "5px",
                            "overlay-opacity": "0",
                            "text-valign": "center",
                            "text-halign": "center",
                            "width": "50px",
                            "height": "50px",
                            "shape": "circle"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        selector: 'node[label = "Movie"]',
                        css: {
                            'background-color': '#F5A45D', 'content': 'data(title)', "font-size": "5px",
                            "text-valign": "center",
                            "text-halign": "center",
                            "width": "50px",
                            "height": "50px",
                            "shape": "circle",
                            "overlay-opacity": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        selector: 'edge',
                        css: {
                            'content': 'data(relationship)', 'target-arrow-shape': 'vee', "font-size": "5px",
                            'curve-style': 'bezier',
                            "line-style": "solid",
                            "width": normalLineWidth,
                            "overlay-opacity": "0",
                        }
                    }
                ],
                elements: {
                    nodes: [
                        {data: {id: '172', name: 'Tom', label: 'Person'}, position: { x: 300, y: 300 }},
                        {data: {id: '173', name: 'Jack', label: 'Person'}, position: { x: 400, y: 230 }},
                        {data: {id: '174', name: 'Mike', label: 'Person'}, position: { x: 210, y: 350 }},
                        {data: {id: '175', name: 'Lucy', label: 'Person'}, position: { x: 80, y: 60 }},
                        {data: {id: '183', title: 'ABC', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 370, y: 390 }},
                        {data: {id: '184', title: 'EFG', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 200, y: 100 }},
                        {data: {id: '185', title: 'movie3', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 130, y: 165 }},
                        {data: {id: '186', title: 'movie4', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 278, y: 55 }},
                        {data: {id: '187', title: 'movie5', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 180, y: 30 }},
                        {data: {id: '188', title: 'movie6', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 90, y: 290 }},
                        {data: {id: '189', title: 'movie7', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 45, y: 150 }},
                        {data: {id: '190', title: 'movie8', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 250, y: 200 }},
                        {data: {id: '191', title: 'movie9', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 300, y: 400 }},
                        {data: {id: '192', title: 'movie10', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 500, y: 300 }},
                        {data: {id: '193', title: 'movie11', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 280, y: 120 }},
                        {data: {id: '194', title: 'movie112', label: 'Movie'}, position: { x: 80, y: 196 }},
                    ],
                    edges: [{data: {source: '172', target: '183', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '172', target: '185', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '173', target: '187', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '174', target: '188', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '175', target: '184', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '172', target: '183', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '172', target: '192', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '172', target: '194', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '172', target: '190', relationship: 'like'}},
                        {data: {source: '172', target: '183', relationship: 'like'}},
                    ]
                },
                layout: {
                    name: 'preset',
                }
            });

            bindEventHandler();
            console.log("--------------------------");

            cy.on('click', function (event) {
                if (event.target === cy) {
                    cy.elements()
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .style("events", "yes");
                    console.log('tap on background');
                } else {
                    console.log('tap on some element');
                }
            });

            cy.on('click', 'node', function (evt) {
                console.log("======================");
                console.log(evt.target.style());
                let toHighlightElements = getToHighlightElements(evt);

                // cy.startBatch();
                cy.elements().style({"events":"no", "opacity":"0.2", "text-opacity":"0"});
                console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
                console.log(evt.target.style());

                toHighlightElements
                    .style("opacity", 1);

                evt.target.connectedEdges().style("width", highlightLineWidth);
                // cy.endBatch();

            });

            function getToHighlightElements(evt) {
                let result = cy.collection();
                let tapNode = evt.target;

                result.merge(tapNode).merge(tapNode.neighborhood());

                return result;
            }

            function getToIgnoreElements(eles) {
                if (eles) {
                    return cy.elements().unmerge(eles);
                } else {
                    return cy.elements();
                }
            }

            function bindEventHandler() {
                cy.on('mouseover', 'edge', edgeMouseOverHandler);
                cy.on('mouseout', 'edge', edgeMouseOutHandler);
                cy.on('mouseover', 'node', nodeMouseOverHandler);
                cy.on('mouseout', 'node', nodeMouseOutHandler);
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Describe expected : when set "text-opacity":"0" the label text on element is invisible.

Actual results: after set the style, scroll the mouse to zoom-in the graph, text invisible, scroll the mouse to zoom-out the graph, the text visible again.

Comment: If you want to disable nodes, there are other options for that like [nodes.ungrabify()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.ungrabify) or [nodes.lock()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.lock)

Comment: Thank you for your answer~the options you mentioned is useful.On the other hand, I find a css option called "min-zoomed-font-size", by using this option, when zoom in or out, the label on the node can be setted to display or no display.